# CodeIgniter URL

Tags: url, codeigniter

Sorry, but something weird is happening to me. I thought I should share.

Everything works fine in my CodeIgniter install doing local development, but I noticed that if I for example clicked on a link with the value of `href` being “controller/function” everything works fine. If I try to navigate to another page (essentially to another function inside my controller, say “controller/function1”, my CodeIgniter stacks the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). The following is an example of what it does!

```
http://localhost/wayefoundation/index.php/mainpage/mainpage/programs
```

I was checking the community and only CodeIgniter 1.5.3 was mentioned to have some sort of bug even though I believe to check myself as well. What is happening to the URL above?

Comment: The link you posted will only work on your machine.  Post a link with a proper domain name, not "localhost".

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Sorry about the link, but I had to use `site_url()`. All the links were fine. I did not have a case of "accumulated links" in my address bar. So I did this for all my `hrefs`,

```
site_url("controller/method")
```